# Open Web Crawling Dumps

Tags: data-request, web-crawling

I am currently using the [Common Crawl](http://commoncrawl.org/) dump of web crawl data. Are their any other good providers of free web crawling data that I can blend with my Common Crawl data?

Comment: Are you looking for any specific kind of data? Or, in other words, why are you looking to extend the Common Crawl dump with data from other sources?

Comment: Yes, there are URLs in my training set of data that are not found in Common Crawl, so I would like to supplement common crawl data with any other sources.

Answer (score 7):

If the crawled data doesn't need to be very recent, the [Internet Archive](http://archive.org/) provides [80 terabytes of archived web crawl data from 2011 for research](http://blog.archive.org/2012/10/26/80-terabytes-of-archived-web-crawl-data-available-for-research/). Unfortunately, they don't say under which license they release the data, so it might not be Open Data as defined by the [Open Definition](http://opendefinition.org/).

Comment: I would prefer recent and one that is kept up to date like common crawl.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure there aren't, but your best bet would probably be to ask on the Common Crawl [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/common-crawl).  That's a place where people who are interested in this kind of stuff hang out and it's low enough traffic that a polite request wouldn't be out of line -- the answer would probably be of interest to the entire community there.